# How to implement BoundedVec inside an extrinsic?

Tags: boundedvec

I need to check if an extrinsic matches "default" inside an extrinsic.  The following works:

`let bv: BoundedVec<u8, T::StringLimit> = "default".as_bytes().to_vec().try_into().unwrap();`

However, this seems kind of ugly and hacky.  Is there not a better way to construct a BoundedVec?

> Blockquote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more elegant way:

1. Make your max value part of your pallet's configuration trait so you can keep it generic in your pallet:

```
#[pallet::constant]
type StringLimit: Get<u32>;
```

2. Define some alias for your bounded vec (outside of `pub mod pallet{}`):

```
type MyBoundedVec<T> = BoundedVec<u8, <T as Config>::StringLimit>;
```

3. Then, use it inside your extrinsic:

```
let my_bounded_vec: MyBoundedVec<T> =
    "default".as_bytes().to_vec().try_into().unwrap();
```

Comment: should never unwrap in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you also have the `bounded_vec!` macro which is similar to the `vec!` macro.